# fibonacci text sequence special property

Tags: regex, math

Could anyone please let me know about some special properties of the fibonacci numbers/text representation. More specifically, I am interested when the subwords or at which indexes the words match partially or fully.

For example

```
w0 = a
w1 = b
w2 = ba
w3 = **b**a**b** - 0 and 2nd index match for w3
w4 = **ba**b**ba** - here the first two and last two indexes match and so on.
```

In other words, do you know any special pattern matching properties of the fibonacci words? Or possibly if you can know some good source on the topic.

Thanks

Comment: Which regex did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Thing that can be used for it is called "border array", it is array, which at given position of your String shows you what longest prefix is also a suffix.

```
Algorithm Border Array Construction
Output: Border array H for string w (stored in array of char "x").
1: H[1] ← 0
2: for i ← 1..(n − 1) do
3: b ← H[i]
4: while b > 0 and x[i + 1] != x[b + 1] do
5: b ← H[b]
6: end while
7: if x[i + 1] = x[b + 1] then
8: H[i + 1] ← b + 1
9: else
10: H[i + 1] ← 0
11: end if
12: end for
```

Example :

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
x a b a a b a b a ∗
H 0 0 1 1 2 3 2 3 ?
```